# DataBindings are broken after update to MvvmCross 4.0 when using AppCompatActivity

Tags: data-binding, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, android-appcompat

I'm using the android toolbar at my MvvmCross 3.5.1 app but once I updated it to MvvmCross 4.0 databindings are broken. As long as there is no base appcompat activity I have to implement my own:

```
MvxActionBarEventSourceActivity : AppCompatActivity , IMvxEventSourceActivity
{
 ...
}
```

And then base bindable mvx activity:

```
MvxActionBarActivity : MvxActionBarEventSourceActivity, IMvxAndroidView
{
 ...
}
```

App starts just fine and I can see my toolbar but bindings are just "silent" and don't work. Same implementation works find for MvvmCross 3.5.

You can find full sample here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19503836/MvvmCross4_Toolbar_Bindings.zip

Please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override `OnCreateView` and `AttachBaseContext` and use the `MvxAppCompatActivityHelper` to support bindings: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/blob/master/MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat/MvxAppCompatActivity.cs#L78

```
    public override View OnCreateView(View parent, string name, Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
    {
        var view = MvxAppCompatActivityHelper.OnCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs);
        return view ?? base.OnCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs);
    }

    protected override void AttachBaseContext(Context @base)
    {
        base.AttachBaseContext(MvxContextWrapper.Wrap(@base, this));
    }
```

There is a sample available to implement `Toolbar` instead of `Actionbar` too: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Samples

Comment: works like a charm! I did used the MvxAppCompatActivity from the mvvmcross support nuget package and it works great. Thank you!

Comment: Dead mvvmcross links.